# __pv_stub(x, t, "add", __PV_BITS_31_24)... why __PV_BITS_31_24 is 0x8100_0000?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, inline-assembly

The function

```
__virt_to_phys(unsigned long x)
```

which boils down to

```
__pv_stub(x, t, "add", __PV_BITS_31_24);
```

__pv_stub macro expands to

```
add  t, x, 0x8100_0000
```

Apart from inserting a pointer to this instruction in .pv_table section, which can be used to patch this add instruction during bootup.
My question is regarding the constant __PV_BITS_31_24. Is there any reason to use the value 0x8100_0000 for it.

As per my understanding this value makes 12 bit immediate encoding field of add instruction as 481 hex. At run time during bootup function __fix_pv_table changes it to 4C0 hex(assume start of first mem bank at 0x8000_0000).
Is the value 0x8100_0000 so common such that people have decided to use it as default value during compilation and if its different then anyway it'll be fixed during bootup ? Or there is some different reason for this which I am completely unable to understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, because it has bits 31 and 24 set, thus results in the appropriate instruction encoding for patching the MSB of the offset.

Remember that immediate constants in ARM instructions are formed from an 8-bit value rotated to one of 16 positions in the 32-bit word. Assembling the initial value of 0x81000000 guarantees the appropriate rotation for bits 31:24 is encoded, so then any other 8-bit value can then be written over the bottom byte of the instruction without worrying about the rest.

It equally could have been 0xff000000 (or any other value which had at least bits 24 and 30 or 31 set), but apparently [that particular value was was a relatively arbitrary decision by the maintainer](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.arm.kernel/101446/focus=101477).